# richface fileUpload onerror does not fire up

Tags: java, file-upload, richfaces

I have a Richfaces component - `fileUpload` it's `onerror` method does not fire up even if server cast an exception. Here is component' code :

```
                        <rich:fileUpload

                            immediateUpload="true" 
                            acceptedTypes="pdf, txt, rtf, xls, xlsx, doc, docx, ppt, pptx, jpg, jpeg, mpg, mpeg"
                            allowFlash="true"
                            maxFilesQuantity="1"

                            fileUploadListener="#{bean.listener}"

                            onerror="alert('error');"
                            onuploadcomplete="alert('complete');"
                            >
                            <f:attribute name="typ" value="#{cc.attrs.typ}"></f:attribute>
                        </rich:fileUpload>
```

My `bean.listener` looks like this :

```
public void listener(final FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException, ConversionException {
    throw new RuntimeException("haha");

}
```

in any case the only thing I get is `complete` message. The version of RichFaces is `4.2.3`.
Did any one faced such problem?

Thanks.

**UPD.**

Ok, I checked out Richfaces 4 documentation and there is actually no `onerror` event. Seems like any result is success for the framework. So now the question is how do I react on exception from server?

Answer (score 1):

You can to listen to the `uploadcomplete`. It sends along items the state of which you can check, e.g.:

```
onuploadcomplete="checkItems(event)"
…

checkItems = function(event) {
    var items = event.rf.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].state == "serverError") { // and/or "sizeExceeded"
            alert('error');
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Ah I see you're firing the exception in the listener. The exceptions you're going to catch this way will be related to getting the file to the server. At the time the listener is called the component has delivered the file, hence the state is "done". You'll have to handle the exceptions that happen in the listener yourself.

Comment: By some reason the "state" valriable is "done" and not "serverError".